# Updated DATE field values in form are not submitted - problem

Tags: javascript, forms, date, submit

I have some code that successfully inputs a variety of values into a form on a webpage and I can see that the data is put into the correct fields in the correct format.  When I submit the form using the 'OK' button, or code, the process completes but the Date data carried through is the current date, despite the fact that I can see a different date displayed in the field.  I can cut and paste data into the field from e.g., Notepad and it works fine.

Here is the html for the beginning of the form:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
                <div class="columns group">
                    <div class="formColumn flex">

    <div id="editConference_ownerField" style="display: none">
        <div class="formRow">
            <div class="labelBlock" id="editConference_ownerLbl">Owner</div>
            <div class="fieldBlock fillspace">
                <select id="editConference_owner"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

// The first input in this class loads find and is pulled through when the form is submitted using the OK button  

    <div class="formRow">
        <label class="labelBlock" id="editConference_labelLbl" for="editConference_label">Title</label>
        <div class="fieldBlock fillspace">
            <input type="text" class="input" id="editConference_label" maxlength="256" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="editConference_timeFields" style="">

    <div class="formRow">
        <div class="labelBlock" id="editConference_startLbl">Start</div>
        <div class="fieldBlock calendarBlock">
            <input type="date" id="editConference_startNative" class="native_date has_native">

// The element id="editConference_start" is a date and does NOT pull through

            <input type="text" id="editConference_start" class="sl_date has_native" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">

// The element id="editConference_startTime" is a time DOES pull through!      

            <input type="text" id="editConference_startTime" placeholder="Time" class="ui-timepicker-input" autocomplete="off">

            <div id="start-date-picker"><div class="pika-single is-hidden is-bound" style="position: static; left: auto; top: auto;"></div></div>
            <div id="start-time-picker"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formRow">
        <div class="labelBlock" id="editConference_endLbl">End</div>
        <div class="fieldBlock calendarBlock">
            <input type="date" id="editConference_endNative" class="native_date has_native">

            <input type="text" id="editConference_end" class="sl_date has_native" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">

            <input type="text" id="editConference_endTime" placeholder="Time" class="ui-timepicker-input" autocomplete="off">
            <div id="end-date-picker"><div class="pika-single is-hidden is-bound" style="position: static; left: auto; top: auto;"></div></div>
            <div id="end-time-picker"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the Javascript that I have been using. I have been testing it out using the Chrome F12 Console and working inside the iframe. All the inputs used appear to be of `type="text"`.  It automates the filling out of the form except the problem noted above and submits it:

```
\\Loading the data into the fields

    var Title = "Coding syntax test again";
    document.getElementById('editConference_label').value = Title;

    var StDate = "06/05/2020";
    document.getElementById('editConference_start').value = StDate;

    var StTime = "16:20";
    document.getElementById('editConference_startTime').value = StTime;

    var EndDate = "06/05/2020";
    document.getElementById('editConference_end').value = EndDate;

    var EndTime = "17:50";
    document.getElementById('editConference_endTime').value = EndTime;

    var Desc = "The conference description stuff";
    document.getElementById('editConference_description').value = Desc;

\\ Click 'OK'

    document.getElementById("editConference_ok").click();
```

Things tried:

1) Using the code below to enter data via the id ="editConference_startNative" element.  It does not seem to work but I am not sure if my code makes any sense or if this something worth pursing:

```
var StDate = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
StDate.value = '2020-05-05';
document.getElementById('editConference_startNative').value = StDate;
```

2) Creating a var with a date type for use with the Native version of the input

```
var StDate = new Date("05/05/2020");
document.getElementById('editConference_startNative').value = StDate;
```

I think the output is in the wrong form to be used but can't figure out how to shorten it in the right format.  Perhaps this is not the right approach.

3) Removing the final click code then waiting for a few seconds and them adding the Click line in and executing but this did not work so I presume it is not a question of a delay.  I also tried this code before the click code for a delay but I am not sure if it is valid:

```
setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);
document.getElementById("editConference_ok").click();
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: When posting, please reduce your code to the minimum required to show the issue, e.g. all those DIVs, class and style attributes could be cut and you probably only need one date field. Often, in simplifying the code, the issue will become apparent. Or not. But it still makes the job of finding the issue much easier. :-)

Comment: I voted to close because: there is no "OK" button in the form, so no way to manually submit it, none of the controls have a name, so submitting the form won't submit any data so impossible to replicate your issue even if a submit button is added to the form. Once you've updated the question so it's possible to replicate the issue, you'll likely get help.

Comment: Thank you RobG for your comments.  I am new to posting so will have another go taking your comments into account. (I wasn't sure about removing the copious divs as they might have contained the vital information.